# iPhone files not persistent

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone app I have written in C# using MonoTouch. Everything works fine, but there is something funny going on with the files created by my application (a small sqLite database and a temp file). The files seem to exis while the app is resident in memory, but the moment i re-boot my phone, the files are gone (?) As a result the app keeps forgetting what it's doing so to speak.

As adviced in the monotouch docs, I store my files under the "personal" folder. This works fine both on the emulator and my real phone. But as mentioned, the files vanish into thin air if i re-boot or leave the phone alone for a couple of hours (note: as long as the app is running and has focus, everything is ok. iOS seems to keep apps resident even if you exit to the menu).

This is an example of how I get the path for my temp-file:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);  
return Path.Combine(documents,"tr_activeTask.dat");
```

I realize that each iPhone app has it's own "personal" folder, which is backed up by iPhone amoung other things. Have anyone experienced this behavior? I cant figure out the cause. Is it somehow connected to the provisioning profile i use (ad-hoc testing)?

Comment: What path is returned by GetFolderPath?  In other apps I've made, I used NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, I believe.  I wonder if this points to a different directory.

Comment: I thought the bundle-path was read only? I'll try the call you mention & get back 2 you asap

Comment: Let me know if that works, I posted another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at my app, and I have this:

```
BaseDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..");
Documents = Path.Combine(BaseDir, "Documents");
```

This Documents folder is where I store everything.

Comment: I found the error. There seem to have been a conflict in the way i accessed the files (i use norwegian locale elsewhere). That was a day of debugging out the window. So this was my bad .. I also tested the reply you gave here. It was a bit confusing, because the two lines of code you gave above basically results in the same path. You add ".." to the path, which means "cd up", then you add "documents". The problem is, it was already in documents (specialfolder.personal = documents). But thanks for taking the time to help out. It was when i tested your appbundle thing that i went "aha" :)

Comment: Yeah, I have a couple other paths below this code that require the ".." such as: "Library/Preferences" and "Settings.bundle".